# Accessing private key, via keyring programatically

Tags: cosmos-sdk

I have created a keyring for my cosmos chain using the "--keyring-backend file"
I want to be able to access this in one of my external services to the chain, running on the alongside the node

```golang
reader := bytes.NewBufferString(passwd)
reader.WriteByte('\n')
keyring.New(sdk.KeyringServiceName(), keyring.BackendFile, cliDir, reader)
```

This panics with

```
too many failed passphrase attempts [recovered]
```